# Change opentext to opendialog

Tags: c#

Hi i would like to select the text file using dialog form instead of having to use the path given.  How would i do this?

I want to replace opentext with opendialog? I've tried but I get errors with stream i want to use streamreader....

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText("c:\\myparts.txt"))
        {
            label3.Text = "Ready to Insert";
            textBox7.Text = reader.ReadLine();
            textBox8.Text = reader.ReadLine();
            textBox9.Text = reader.ReadLine();
            textBox10.Text = reader.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Opendialog returns the path to the file selected, not a stream, you need to use that as the parameter to opentext.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to replace opentext with **opendialog**? I've tried but I get
>   errors with stream i want to use streamreader....

**Solution 1 :** You can assign `Stream` returned by  `openFileDialog.OpenFile()` to the `StreamReader`

Try This:

```
     if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.OpenFile()))
            {
                label3.Text = "Ready to Insert";
                textBox7.Text = reader.ReadLine();
                textBox8.Text = reader.ReadLine();
                textBox9.Text = reader.ReadLine();
                textBox10.Text = reader.ReadLine();
            }
        }
```

**Solution 2 :** You can directly assign the `openFileDialog().FileName` property as 
`Path` argument to the `File.OpenText()` method as below:

```
      if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.OpenText(openFileDialog1.FileName)))
            {
                label3.Text = "Ready to Insert";
                textBox7.Text = reader.ReadLine();
                textBox8.Text = reader.ReadLine();
                textBox9.Text = reader.ReadLine();
                textBox10.Text = reader.ReadLine();
            }
        }
```

**Solution 3:** if you want to assign file content to the  multiple textbox'es

Try this:

```
int startCount=7;
int endCount=10;
string preText="textBox";
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
   String fileName=openFileDialog1.FileName;
   foreach(var line in File.ReadLines(fileName))
   {
     ((TextBox) (this.Controls.Find(preText+startCount,true)[0])).Text=line;
     if(startCount==endCount)
       break;

       startCount++;
    }
}
```

**Note 1:** All TextBoxControls should be started with `preText` value.
**Note 2:** in the above solution you can change the `startCount` and `endCount` as per your requirement.

for example if you want to assign file contenet to 20 Textbox controls starting from `textBox3` to `textBox23` you need to change parameters in above code as below:

```
preText="textBox";
startCount = 3;
endCount = 23;
```

Answer (score 4):

Do you want something like this ?

```
OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();

if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    using (var reader = File.OpenText(dlg.FileName))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string fileToOpen = "";

        OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        dialog.Title = "Browse for file...";
        dialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

        DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();

        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            fileToOpen = dialog.FileName;
        }

        using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(fileToOpen))
        {
            label3.Text = "Ready to Insert";
            textBox7.Text = reader.ReadLine();
            textBox8.Text = reader.ReadLine();
            textBox9.Text = reader.ReadLine();
            textBox10.Text = reader.ReadLine();
        }
}
```

Comment: If this is the solution you went with. Please feel free to "check" this as the answer. ;) Glad I could help.